# python programming relating to correlation

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset, and the program is supposed to return a 32 by 32 matrix, but instead it is returning a 1 by 1 matrix. This is the dataset I am working on.[click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XXOKBOGErF--xHyC5ijJ1rlKy-O3jCZZ)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import csv
def correlation(data, threshold):
    dataset1=[]
    tuples = 0
    flag = False
    with open(data, 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if flag == False:
        if not row[0].isdigit():
            flag = True
            continue
        tuples += 1
        dataset1.append(row)

    for i in range(len(dataset1)):
            # Yes : 1 No : 0
    if dataset1[i][-1] == 'Yes' or dataset1[i][-1] == '1' or dataset1[i][-1] == 'M' or dataset1[i][-1] == 'malignant':
        dataset1[i][-1] = 1
    elif dataset1[i][-1] == 'No'or dataset1[i][-1] == '0' or dataset1[i][-1] == 'B' or dataset1[i][-1] == 'benign':
        dataset1[i][-1] = 0
    col_corr = set() # Set of all the names of deleted columns
    dataset=pd.DataFrame(dataset1)

    corr_matrix=set()
    dataset.astype(float)
    print(dataset)
    corr_matrix = dataset.corr()
    print len(corr_matrix.columns)
    print corr_matrix
    for i in range(len(corr_matrix.columns)):
        for j in range(i):
            if corr_matrix.iloc[i, j] >= threshold:
                colname = corr_matrix.columns[i] # getting the name of column
                col_corr.add(colname)
                if colname in dataset.columns:
                    del dataset[colname] # deleting the column from the dataset

    print(dataset)

correlation("big.csv",0.7)
```

`dataset.corr()` should return a 32 by 32 matrix but it is returning a 1 by 1 matrix as output instead. Why?

Comment: what does dataset look like after you print it?

Comment: its a matrix of 569*32

Comment: the corr will return a 32*32 data frame. could you print shape of dataset to check?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `corr` function on a dataFrame do the following:

> Compute pairwise correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values [[ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)]

You may have only a single column. You can try to transpose your data.